# Inputs needed to create command line utility using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, command-line, command

We are trying to create a command line utility using node.js.
We need to create something like [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) utility like user will start the utility with one command, which will open its own terminal where we can execute sub commands.
The reason why we need to create our own nested terminal is that we need to initialize few variables in one command and should be able to retrieve them in second and so on...

so we have some questions:
1) Is node.js suitable for this? , we tried using [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) but it creates commands, does not maintain session '
2) we tried [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/inquirer) + [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) + [node-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd) but it is also giving issues.

Maybe our approach here is wrong and someone can guide us around this? Any inputs in this direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: This question might be too broad for StackOverflow.  Can you refine your question  to be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You have approached the problem from the incorrect angle. `commander` or `node-cmd` allow you to run shell commands inside a node program. What you need is to actually implement a shell.

Your starting point should be the [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module, that allows you to process `stdin` data. This simple example shows how to create a shell that handles 2 commands: `hello` and `exit`:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('> ', (answer) => {
  if (answer == "hello") {
    console.log("world");
  }

  if (answer == "exit") {
    rl.close();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, we were thinking this as our second option. Is this the way all command line are created ???

Comment: it's just a starting point if you want to use node, but there are other technologies out there for building command line tools

Answer (score 0):

*"Is node.js suitable for this?"*
Sure, why not ? You can do everything you want with Node.js

Abviously you could create it from scratch, but there are some good libraries that can help you with this task. You have already tried some of them.

Personnaly, I would give a try to [Vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal) to make a cli app:

```
const vorpal = require('vorpal')();

let variables = {};

vorpal
  .command('init', 'Initialise few variables.')
  .action(function() {
    return this.prompt({
      name: 'etherum_password',
      message: 'Please enter your etherum wallet password: '
    }, (result) => {
      variables = result
    })
  });

vorpal
  .command('pswd', 'Show etherum wallet password.')
  .action(function() {
    if (variables.etherum_password)
      this.log(variables.etherum_password)
    else this.log('Please run \'init\' command before.');
  });

vorpal
  .delimiter('$')
  .show();
```

Note that the [prompt](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/API-%7C-CommandInstance#commandinstancepromptobject-callback) method is directly inspired by *Inquirer.js*